# php drawing based on csv data

Tags: php, html, csv

What I am trying to do is load some values from a csv file, and use them as the x, y values to draw some rectangles.

I am loading the file, but instead of displaying the images, I am outputting the raw image data. I know that in the html code I can use

```
<img scr="foo.php"></script>
```

to display the image correctly, but I don't know how to use this to draw multiple rectangles based off each row of data in the csv file. Please help.

csv code

```
20,40,60,80
50,100,150,175
```

index php code

```
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
            include("parse.php");
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

parse php code

```
<?php

include("draw.php");

$file = fopen("data.csv", "r");
while (!feof($file)) {
    $line = fgetcsv($file);

        drawGraph($line[0], $line[1], $line[2], $line[3]);

}
fclose($file);
?>
```

draw php code

```
<?php

function drawGraph($xPos, $yPos, $xxPos, $yyPos) {

//create a 200 x 200 canvas image
$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 200);

//set canvas background to white
$white = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($canvas, 0, 0, $white);

//create colors
$pink = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 255, 105, 180);

//draw rectangles
imagerectangle($canvas, $xPos, $yPos, $xxPos, $yyPos, $pink);

//ERROR - following line displays raw data of image not the actural image
imagepng($canvas);

imagedestroy($canvas);
}

?>
```

Comment: I actually didn't understand you completely, but maybe this helps:  Remember to do header('Content-Type: image/png') before pushing the raw data.

Comment: Can you post the resulting HTML?

Comment: This is some of the html output with no header       ‰PNG  IHDRÈÈ":9É=IDATxœíÜÁ Ã0A;¤»t’‚Ò‰ëSÈÃA^fæ/t ýnclpµÇê¸'a‘ a‘ a‘ a‘ a‘ a‘ a‘ a‘ a‘ a‘ a‘ a‘ a‘ a‘ a‘ a‘ a‘ a‘ a‘‰çÔé÷qÑÿû¼–]Í sam‹xaÐœã+$!,Â"!,Â"!,Â"!,Â"!,Â"!,Â"!,Â"!,Â"!,Â"!,Â"!,Â"!,Â"!,Â"!,Â"!,Â"!,Â"!,Â"!,Â"!,Óë¸mÆæ—}Œ±znÈWHBX$„EBX$„EBX$„EBX$„EBX$„EBX$„EBX$„EBX$„EBX$„EBX$„EBX$„EBX$„EBX$„EBX$„EBX$„EBX$„EBX$„EBX$„EBX$„EBX$„EBX$„EBX$„EBX

Comment: With a header add the raw data display the "broken image" link, so something isn't quite right.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a Content-Type header telling the browser the data is  image.  If you do this with your drawGraph function it's going to output raw data no matter.

```
<html>
    <body>
            <?php
                include("parse.php");
            ?>
        </body>
</html>
```

You probably want to do it with drawGraph returning into the image itself.  Such that like you showed originally  and then make sure to use
     `header('Content-Type: image/png');`
or equivalent to what you are generating.

If you want to test it directly in the browser you need to drop the tags from your example and just put `<?PHP include("parse.php"); ?>`with no other characters outside the php tags (if you leave extra spaces or newlines it's going to think it's part of your image.

**Edit: Missed the loop issue.**

Remember that your drawGraph function creates and displays a single png in imagepng which means if you call it multiple times in your example it's going to be separate PNG images all mushed together.  You probably want to instantiate the image and just draw your rectangles in the loop, then finally output the image.

```
//create a 200 x 200 canvas image
$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 200);

//set canvas background to white
$white = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($canvas, 0, 0, $white);

//create colors
$pink = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 255, 105, 180);

$file = fopen("data.csv", "r");
while (!feof($file)) {
    $line = fgetcsv($file);

    //draw rectangles
    imagerectangle($canvas, $line[0], $line[1], $line[2], $line[3], $pink);

}

fclose($file);


/** finally output entire single png **/    
//ERROR - following line displays raw data of image not the actural image
imagepng($canvas);

imagedestroy($canvas);
```

Comment: I've already tried a header with Content-Type: image/png, but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you had removed all extraneous characters?  It's literally the textbook example http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php

Comment: OK I just tried again adding the header to the index.php file. It still doesn't work but, like before, displays the "broken link" icon for an image.

Comment: You're missing some trailing spaces, I would almost bet or you're header isn't formatted properly.  You'll have to use some debugging with the browser to see what it's receiving if you don't see it right away.  You literally cannot have "<?php // image stuff ?>   " for the file.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with why I can't have <?php // image stuff ?> for the file. Shouldn't the php file be able to "return" an image to be displayed by the browser?

Comment: It can my indication of the trailing space was all I meant.  I did take the liberty of testing your code and it works fine and draws rectangles.

Comment: Really, using the csv file? What browser are you using?

Comment: No just the draw graph function I just output the php result to a png.     `php testimg.php > test.png`  testimg.php - http://pastebin.com/Ac9pGiBS

Comment: You know what I just saw that you are calling the drawGraph in a loop though but imagepng generates a single PNG, if you have multiple rectangles it's going to break because you'll be chunk-ing them altogether making nonsense.  Is that what's coming from the CSV?

Comment: That would probably be the reason for the "broken image link", the header may be working now so it is no longer out putting raw data in the browser, but the multiple rectangle in the imagepng is causing the break.

Comment: Yeah sorry I read to fast.  I updated the answer to consolidate your loop, it's a bit crude but works for illustration.

Comment: OK, so in the loop you have basically combined the old draw.php and parse.php into one. correct? What I have now done is take the index.php and use the include to run the "new loop" code you created but it's still not working for me. What did you do?

Comment: I was just writing in the editor, the idea is you need to draw the rectangles during the single image create, then output the result.  Okay, I did a simple test without the csv (for loop cascade rects) and it works.  Edit: I updated the pastebin for you http://pastebin.com/iHMEysyR.

Comment: ok, now I am really confused, the pastebin example is meant to be working, but it's not for me, if you place the pastebin code into a single .php and run this (with wamp), it should work, correct?

Comment: It does work but no I didn't run it in an http server or bother with http content issues, just dumped output to a png and opened the png to view resulting rectangles.  So if you run it there, you'll have to add back in the Content-Type header.

Comment: That's odd.  Here's the image I output with that code http://tinypic.com/r/118esys/6 i.e. `php testimg.php > test.png`.  I'm heading out in a few, I'll check back tomorrow.